# ccTouchesBegan not firing in cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hello, I have created a layer for a demo game application using cocos2D Framework. I have integrating cocos2d with existing application. I need to detect Touch Events for that. But I am not able to Detect that.I have used ccTouchesBegan.

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self ccTouchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Even simple touchBegan event is also not fired.

do I have to add anything like delegate or Protocol for that ? I am new in iphone development and also I am learning cocos2d programming for game development . please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `init` method of the layer, you need to tell it to respond to touches by setting `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`.